# Finding time through regex

Tags: regex

I need to find retrieve time from a given text for e.g. Join us for dinner tonight til 10PM #LeBunSocial @3compasses #e8 #Dalston

For the above condition below code works perfectly fine

```
  if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"(?'hour'\d{2})(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm|Pm)", RegexOptions.Compiled)) //2 digits + pm/AM" (without space)
        {
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?'hour'\d{2})(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm|Pm)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            result = true;
            counter++;
        }
```

But due to some business reasons i have to execute below code as well. Regex should not match for 10PM as 1 digit restriction is mentioned below but still it matches with below regex. How to avoid it ? below code should only work with (for e.g. 1PM) 1 digit

```
 if (Regex.IsMatch(str, @"(?'hour'\d{1})(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm|Pm)", RegexOptions.Compiled)) // 1 digit + AM/PM without space
        {
            m = Regex.Match(str, @"(?'hour'\d{1})(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm|Pm)", RegexOptions.Compiled);
            result = true;
            counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\d` (the `{1}` is a no-op because every regex token is matched exactly once unless otherwise specified) matches the `0` in `10`. If you want it to match only single digits, you can use a [negative lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
@"(?<!\d)(?'hour'\d)(?'ampm'AM|am|PM|pm|Pm)"
```

But the entire approach is weird. For example, why not simply make the regex case-insensitive (or do you specifically want to allow `Pm` and disallow `Am`)?

Furthermore, why match against the same regex twice?

Comment: It worked.. any type of AM or Pm will do (any suggestion for making AM PM case-insensitive ?)

If the text has multiple time mentioned then i have to avoid those hence i have kept if statement with a counter. Any suggestion will be very helpful

Comment: You could use the inline `i` modifier. `(?<!\d)(?'hour'\d)(?'ampm'(?i)[ap]m)`

Comment: ok it worked thanks alot. Last help needed  @"(?<!\d)(?'hour'\d)(h) i am using this to find 1 digit + 'h' letter, but it is also working for 2haHKiOrSi.

Comment: @user1037747: The best probably is to use a [word boundary anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html): `@"(?<!\d)(?'hour'\d)h\b"`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a word boundary `\b` before `\d` which ensures that there would be a word boundary must exists before that single digit. `\b` matches between a word character and a non-word character.

```
@"(?'hour'\b\d)(?'ampm'(?i)[ap]m)"
```

`(?i)[ap]m` will do a case insensitive match of `am` or `pm`